# Can I share files over WiFi as a Windows share with my Nexus One?

Tags: wi-fi, windows, files, file-sharing

I have a Nexus One full of songs and when I go to my friend's house I would like to play songs off of it.  Since I have my phone connect to my friend's WiFi, the phone has a local IP.  If my phone's IP address is 192.168.1.101, I would like to be able to navigate to the phone via:

\192.168.1.101\Music

And have it open up a windows folder like any other share.  Then I could copy my songs, play songs off the share, etc.   Is something like this possible?  Is there an app I can buy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebSharing: http://www.appbrain.com/app/websharing-file-media-sync/nextapp.websharing.r1

Comment: Looks very good, and from their website, using WEBDAV in the paid version should let you just use it like a folder in Windows, instead of needing to use the web interface http://android.nextapp.com/site/websharing/doc/webdav will give this a try myself.

Comment: Totally perfect!  As GAThrawn discovered, the WEBDAV version delivers exactly what I want as a conventional windows share (so I can play using my favorite MP3 player instead of in the browser).  Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few apps that will give you similar functionality to what you're looking for.  I'd take a look at [this article](http://www.p2p-blog.com/?itemid=1044), it may be able to point you in the right direction.

[SwiFTP](http://www.cyrket.com/p/android/org.swiftp/) would probably be your best bet, although I don't know if you could STREAM music, which it sounds like is what you're trying to accomplish.  Might just have to copy to his computer via FTP, then open from there.

[EStrong](http://www.cyrket.com/p/android/com.estrongs.android.pop/) has a Samba (Windows File Sharing) client, but I don't believe you can serve files, so that will more than likely not do what you're looking for.

And the other one listed there, [On Air](http://www.cyrket.com/p/android/com.bw.onair/), I'm the least familiar with.  Haven't used a Mac since the screens came in several shades of green, and never had any experience with using the WebDAV protocol in Windows, but based on the description it looks promising.

Comment: Went with Matt's solution, but thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all Android devices gained a new feature called Nearby Share back in 2020.

As of 2023, there is an app for Windows that adds Nearby Share to your PC.

- https://www.android.com/better-together/nearby-share-app/

I'm able to send a 1.2GB file from my phone to my PC at 60MB/s and I'm about thirty feet and four walls away.

[image: Screenshot of Windows Nearby Share receiving file from my Pixe 7.]

Nearby Share uses the fastest possible connection it can establish with both devices. If it is not possible to establish a stable or secure proprietary Wi-Fi Direct connection, then it may fall back to using Bluetooth only. That will always be a magnitude slower.

> Nearby Share uses Bluetooth, Bluetooth Low Energy, WebRTC, UWB, and peer-to-peer Wi-Fi to allow users to share files and links between devices. It was first released on August 4, 2020